# Getting undefined index in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, timezone

I want to get the timezone of a user in php so I did this

```
session_start();
$timeZone = $_SESSION['time'];
```

But I keep getting the error of undefined index time. Please I need help

Comment: And where do you define $_SESSION['time']?

Comment: `$_SESSION['time'] = $timeZone;` how about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to something like this.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['time'] = date_default_timezone_get();
$timeZone = $_SESSION['time'];
```